# Differentiability of distance to a closed convex set

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, convex-geometry, metric-spaces

Let $( \mathbb{R}^d, \| \mathbf{x}\|_2 )$ be a Euclidean Space. For any nonempty closed convex set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, we define
\begin{align}
d(\mathbf{x}, A) = \inf \{ \| \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} \|_2, ~~\mathbf{y}\in A\}.
\end{align}
I was wondering how to prove that $d(\mathbf{x}, A)$ is differentiable and that the gradient is Lipschitz?

Comment: In general, this distance is not differentiable already in $R^2$ at a point $p\in R^2\setminus A$.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński , can you refer or give a counter example?

Comment: Take $A=\{0\}$, $d(x,A)=\|x\|$ is not differentiable at 0.

Comment: Borwein+Lewis Convex Analysis, Section 3.3 Exercise 12(d.iii) characterizes the subdifferential of this function.

Comment: Later in that exercise (d.iv), the gradient is computed for $x\notin A$.

Comment: In general, you'll only have differentiability issues at the boundary of $A$.

Comment: Consider $\ A := \{x\in R^d : ||x|| \ge 1\}.\ $ The $\ d(x,A)\ $ is not differentiable at $0\in R^d,\ $ for every $d=1\ 2\ldots\ $ BTW, it'd be more interesting to consider the square of the distance.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński This set $A$ is not convex.

Comment: @FedorPetrov and AmirSagiv and everybody, sorry. I missed word *convex*, of course.

Comment: Usually the better object to study is $d(\cdot,A)^2$ (note the square), as this function has the desired properties, if $|| \cdot ||$ stems from an inner product.

Comment: See also my <a href="http://mathoverflow.net/questions/331782/differentiability-of-the-distance-function-from-a-variable-point-to-a-fixed>similar question</a> with application to constructive analysis

Answer (score 7):

Borwein+Lewis Convex Analysis, Section 3.3 Exercise 12(d) shows that for convex $A$ and $x\notin A$,
$$\nabla f(x) = f(x)^{-1}(x-P_A(x)),$$
where $f(x)=d(x,A)$ is your function and $P_A(x)$ is the projection of $x$ onto $A$ (i.e., the unique $x^*\in A$ achieving the $\inf$). This shows, in particular, that for $x\notin A$, $\|\nabla f(x)\|_2=1$.

The Lipschitz property follows from Borwein+Lewis
Section 2.1 Exercise 8(c.iii), which shows that projection is a contraction.

The full book reference:
Convex Analysis and Nonlinear Optimization, Borwein, Jonathan, Lewis, Adrian S.
http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387295701

Edit: I forgot to state the additional hypothesis that $A$ is closed.