# $C^1$-extension theorem on cones preserving boundedness of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a closed convex cone with a nonempty interior. Let $f:K\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function satisfying $\|\nabla f\|_\infty<\infty$ (if needed, you can further assume $\|\nabla f\|_{\text{Lip}}<\infty$).

Note that the interior of $K$ being nonempty implies that the linear span of all vectors in $K$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$. In this sense, we say that $K$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$.

We also assume that $\nabla f$ exists on $ K$ including the boundary in the following sense: for any fixed $x \in K$, $f(y)-f(x) = (y-x)\cdot \nabla f(x) + o(|y-x|)$ for all $y\in K$ as $y\to x$. (Since $K$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\nabla f(x)$ is unqiue.)

But, we do **not** assume $f$ is bounded and $f$ is allowed to grow linearly.

**Question**: Is there a continuously differentiable function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $F|_K =f$ and $\|\nabla F\|_\infty<\infty$?

I looked at a few versions of Whitney's theorem, but either there is no control on $\nabla F$ or $\|f\|_\infty<\infty$ is required.

It would be great if there were published results to cite directly. If not, my naive attempt to prove this is to make those covering cubes in the proof of Whitney's theorems to scale along the cone.

Comment: $K$ is closed and convex and $K$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$ implies that $K=\mathbb{R}^n$. Also if $f$ is continuously differentiable on the closed $K$, then certainly $\nabla f$ is defined on $\partial K$ since $\partial K\subset K$. Then in what sense $\nabla f$ is defined on $\partial K$? Your question requires numerous clarifications.

Comment: I clarified the meanings. Thanks for pointing them out! @PiotrHajlasz

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$According to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/247713/36721), the distance function $d\colon K^c\to\R$ to $K$ given by the formula
$$d(x):=\min\{|y-x|\colon y\in K\}$$
for $x\in K^c:=\R^n\setminus K$ is differentiable, where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm.

So, I think the formula
$$F(x):=\int_{C_x}[f(y)+\nabla f(y)\cdot(x-y)]\,dy\Big/\int_{C_x}\,dy$$
for $x\in K^c$, where $C_x:=\{y\in K\colon |y-x|\le2d(x)\}$, will provide a desired extension of $f$. However, I have not checked the details.

Comment: Thank you! But, the link to ``the answer'' is not working. Can you fix it?

Comment: @mathoverflow_user : Thank you for your comment. The link is now fixed, I think.

Comment: I can't verifying $\nabla F(x) = \nabla f(x)$ for $x\in \partial K$, which should hold because $K$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $F(z) - F(x) = ⨍_{C_z} (y-x)\cdot \nabla f(x)+o(|y-x|) d y$, comparing this with $(z-x)\cdot \nabla f(x)$ we want to make sure that $⨍_{C_z}(y-z)\cdot\nabla f(x) d y=o(|z-x|)$. This is where I don't think it works in general.

Comment: @mathoverflow_user : Do you want to look at the modified suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I can verify that $F$ is differentiable on $K$. But I can't verify that on $K^c$. Maybe it's easy since it's away from the boundary, but I am not experienced enough to see it right away. Could you please elaborate on the differentiability on $K^c$? Thank you!

Comment: @mathoverflow_user : I will think about this. Meanwhile, can you provide references to the versions of Whitney's theorem that you have seen?

Comment: Thank you! I looked at versions in Section 2.2 of the [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-0209-3), in particular, Theorems 2.19 and 2.21. Also, Theorem 2.3.6 in the [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-61497-2).

Comment: @mathoverflow_user : I cannot find the meaning of the symbol $\dot{J}^{k,\omega}(\mathbb R^n)$ in part (a) of Theorem 2.19 of the first book (not well written, I think). Can you? (The definitions of $\dot{J}^{k,\omega}_b(\mathbb R^n)$ and $J_b^{k,\omega}(\mathbb R^n)$ at the top of p. 98 in the book are clearly missing the $k$-jet condition.)

Comment: The notation is described in Section 2.1.2 (page 86). They used the shorthand $\dot J^{k,\omega}=J^k \dot C^{k,\omega}$ and $J^{k,\omega}_b = J^kC^{k,\omega}_b$. All decorations are understood to be on $C$.